# Can I compress a directory with a running executable?

Tags: windows, compression, zip, 7-zip, winzip

I've given this a cursory google but most results reference creating executable zip files.

My question is basically:

- I have a running .exe which:

  - Is, in this case, an installer
  - Other items in the directory are related binaries / config files
  - Only one item is written inside this directory during the .exe process, in this case a log file.
  - The .exe is of course *writing* to *other directories* on the system, but not in the .exe's sub-tree.
  - It is of course reading the other files in its directory / sub-directories while running.

**So, can I compress this executable and all files in the directory *while it's installing*? Will the writing to the log file cause any issues?**

My initial theory is that my deployer as a whole should be unaffected by the zip process, which is just reading the files into memory and running it's algorithm on them then writing it's output elsewhere. But the process might get, for want of a better word, *confused* by the log file currently being written inside the directory.

I've attempted this before without any visible issues, but I'd like the peace of mind of someone familiar with the workings of compression tools telling me my suspicions are correct before I implement this parallel execution into my build pipeline.

**Edit:** Another explanation for clarity.

C:\Installer contains:

- .\Installer.exe
- .\Prerequisites\* (binaries etc)
- .\installer_log.txt

I want to run the Installer.exe which is reading from C:\Installer\Prerequisites
It is also writing to C:\Installer\installer_log.txt
It is also writing to another folder, something like C:\Program Files\InstalledProgram - The final, installed program's destination.

While this process is running, I want to compress the folder C:\Installer into C:\Installer.zip

The output file format is irrelevant, in this case I'm using 7zip for compression.

Comment: Why? The reason you want to do this may help us present options you may not have considered that meet your needs. There are other compression methods besides zip, and they may have abilities better suited to your specific problem.

Comment: So are you asking if you can run an executable within a compress archived without uncompressing it? What you are trying to achieve is not clear.

Comment: I'm building a CI/CD pipeline that is time critical, the deployer package is large and zipping it takes a significant amount of time - I want to compress this folder **while** I'm running the installer that's inside it.

Comment: You cannot compress a file that’s being used or accessed by another application.